# Why must JVM class loaders not report problems until first active use?

Tags: java, jvm

I was reading the article below and did not understand the reason behind the following passage:

> Class loaders can opt to load a type early in anticipation of eventual use. If this strategy is chosen, the class loader must not report any problem (by throwing a subclass of java.lang.LinkageError) encountered during loading until the type's first active use. In other words, a type must appear to be loaded only when needed.

Is there a specific reason behind this? What kind of problems could occur and why does it need to be reported specifically during the type's first active use? I only have a limited understanding of the JVM so any other resources would be appreciated.

http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2248831/Java-Class-Loading-The-Basics.htm

Comment: Because the semantics are defined as for lazy loading, and an eager implementation can't change the semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the loader prefetched a group of related classes however the offending class is never actually used then throwing an error would not be useful or necessary.

As for an example of the type of problems that could occur, maybe something like having a malformed regular expression in the class level variable declaration might cause problems at load time.  Or maybe there's a dependency issue where one of the imports is missing.

So, if the class was never used, why throw the error?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is mandated by the Java Language Specification, section [12.2.1 The loading process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2.1) (emphasis mine):

> The loading process is implemented by the class ClassLoader and its
>   subclasses.
>
> Different subclasses of ClassLoader may implement different loading
>   policies. In particular, a class loader may cache binary
>   representations of classes and interfaces, prefetch them based on
>   expected usage, or load a group of related classes together. These
>   activities may not be completely transparent to a running application
>   if, for example, a newly compiled version of a class is not found
>   because an older version is cached by a class loader. **It is the
>   responsibility of a class loader, however, to reflect loading errors
>   only at points in the program where they could have arisen without
>   prefetching or group loading**.
>
> If an error occurs during class loading, then an instance of one of
>   the following subclasses of class LinkageError will be thrown at any
>   point in the program that (directly or indirectly) uses the type:
>
> - ClassCircularityError: A class or interface could not be loaded because it would be its own superclass or superinterface (§8.1.4,
>     §9.1.3, §13.4.4).
> - ClassFormatError: The binary data that purports to specify a requested compiled class or interface is malformed.
> - NoClassDefFoundError: No definition for a requested class or interface could be found by the relevant class loader.
>
> Because loading involves the allocation of new data structures, it may
>   fail with an OutOfMemoryError.